# Colouring the entire row of cells if one cell is coloured

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, colors, formatting

I am currently managing a live spreadsheet that updates regularly.
The spreadsheet is a compilation of lists that change in length over time, that are imported using the "importrange' function. Each list has one total at the very bottom row. And then a new list begins.

Currently, I manually change the fill colour for each of the totals rows a specific colour.
But when the lists change in length, values will be pushed down rows, but the colouring will remain at the original cells.

I have set up conditional formatting (I applied 'if value is greater than 0' to the B column) to colour the (single) total value in the totals row. But I want the entire row to be coloured.
Would there be a way to write a macro or conditional formatting rules to colour the entire row?

I have an example of what I want the spreadsheet to look like below. The letter 'a' means that there will be words in the cell, and the number '1' means that there will be numbers in the cell.
There will be one 'total' value, and I want the entire row to be coloured if there is a total value.

[Image of example spreadsheet layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YcqUj.png)

ie. cells B6 and B15 are totals of the number of entries above (using the COUNTA function), that have been coloured based on conditional formatting. I want the macro/conditional formatting to then colour the entire rows 6 and 15 automatically so it looks like the image.

I am interested to learn about how the specific conditional rules if anyone is willing to explain/link something. Otherwise, just the rule is fine.

Comment: You can color the entire row with conditional formatting too. Just need the correct formula. Therefore I suggest to [edit] your question and post some example data and how the coloring should look like and describe what the rules are (what gets colored and why). Also post the rule you have already set up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this [conditional formatting](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413) custom formula rule for the range `A2:H`:

```
=search("count", formulatext($B2))
```

See [GimelG's explanation](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/91546414?msgid=91591478) and [Lance's explanation](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/60050658?msgid=60238341) of how absolute and relative addresses work in a conditional formatting custom formula rule.

Comment: Thank you for the links. It makes a lot more sense. I tried using the rule you gave me and it didn't work. It did work when I entered the word TOTAL (as I had originally shown) into B6 and B15.


I realise that I was not clear about what I meant. When I said 'total' I was referring to an actual numerical value (counting the number of entries using 'COUNTA'). This value will often change and is not fixed. Sorry about that. I've just update the main question explanation and image to explain this a bit more clearly.

Comment: Edited the answer. Please do not present new requirements after you have received an answer. Ask only [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222741).